# Join two tables, and represent certain row data as column

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables of data, 1 that represents employee data and another that represents employee hours worked. Unfortunately I receive the employee hours data in row format and I need to represent it in column next to the employee data... It's doing my head in... Please see below...

employeehours table:

> ID--------Paycode-------------Hours----workdate
>
> 089999    01 Ordinary --------4.00    -----2013-09-16
>
> 089999    02 Overtime 1.5 ---2.00 -----2013-09-16
>
> 089999    03 Overtime 2.0 ---0.50 -----2013-09-16
>
> 083131    01 Ordinary --------7.60    -----2013-09-16
>
> 083131    02 Overtime 1.5---  0.43-----   2013-09-16

employeedata table:

> ID  ------    Surname -- firstname  --- salarygrade
>   -------------------baserate  ---  otherrate
>
> 089999    SMITH  -----  JOHN  --------     XXX TWU EBA Perm Gr6 -- 
>   23.8508  ----     0.0000

---

I want a query to produce the result as below and I've tried everything to my ability but I CAN'T GET IT TO WORK... I know I may need some php programming to produce the $ values but is it possible to do that through SQL as well? All help is greatly appreciated...

> ID  ------    Surname -- firstname  --- salarygrade
>   ------------------- 01 Hrs--- 01 $ ---- 02 Hrs---- 02 $ ---03 Hrs -03 $
>
> 089999    SMITH  -----  JOHN  --------     XXX TWU EBA Perm Gr6
>   ---4.00----95.4032 -- 2.00 ----71.5524--0.50--23.8508

Some data may not exist for certain Employees with an ID and it would be represented above with 0.00 in certain columns...

This is what I've tried:

```
    <?php
        $result1=mysql_query("SELECT `ID Number`, Surname, `First Name`, `Base Rate`, `Other Rate`, `Salary Code Description`, workdate, employeehours
                                FROM payroll.employeedatanew INNER JOIN payroll.employeehours ON employeedatanew.`ID Number` = employeehours.employeeid
                                GROUP BY Surname ORDER BY Surname Asc
                            ");

        $result2=mysql_query("  SELECT `ID Number`, paycode, workdate, employeehours
                                FROM payroll.employeedatanew INNER JOIN payroll.employeehours ON employeedatanew.`ID Number` = employeehours.employeeid
                                ORDER BY Surname Asc
                            ");


        while($show1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){

        echo("<tr><td>".$show1['ID Number']."</td><td>".$show1['Surname']."</td><td>".$show1['First Name']."</td><td>".substr($show1['Salary Code Description'],11)."</td></tr>");

        }
        ?>
        </table>

        <table>
        <tr>

        <td>1.0x Hrs</td>
        <td>1.0x $</td>
        <!--<td>1.5x Hrs</td>
        <td>1.5x $</td>
        <td>2.0x Hrs</td>
        <td>2.0x $</td>
        <td>Crib Hrs</td>
        <td>Crib $</td>
        <td>Meal Hrs</td>
        <td>Meal $</td> -->

        </tr>
        <?php

        $resultset = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) { $resultset[] = $row;  }

            while($show2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){

            if ($show2['paycode'] == "01 Ordinary" && $show2['ID Number'] == $resultset['ID Number']) {
            echo ("<tr><td>".$show2['employeehours']."</td>");
            $normhourspay = ($show2['employeehours'] * $show3['Base Rate']);
            echo ("<td>".$normhourspay."</td></tr>");
            }           //else {echo("<tr><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>");}}
```

and this:

```
    <table>
    <tr class="tabletitles">
        <td>Employee ID</td>
        <td>Surname</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Pay Grade</td>
        <td>1.0x Hrs</td>
        <td>1.0x $</td>
        <!--<td>1.5x Hrs</td>
        <td>1.5x $</td>
        <td>2.0x Hrs</td>
        <td>2.0x $</td>
        <td>Crib Hrs</td>
        <td>Crib $</td>
        <td>Meal Hrs</td>
        <td>Meal $</td> -->

    </tr>

    <?php
        $result1=mysql_query("SELECT `ID Number`, Surname, `First Name`, `Base Rate`, `Other Rate`, `Salary Code Description`, workdate, employeehours
                                FROM payroll.employeedatanew INNER JOIN payroll.employeehours ON employeedatanew.`ID Number` = employeehours.employeeid
                                GROUP BY Surname ORDER BY Surname Asc
                            ");

        $result2=mysql_query("  SELECT `ID Number`, paycode, workdate, employeehours
                                FROM payroll.employeedatanew INNER JOIN payroll.employeehours ON employeedatanew.`ID Number` = employeehours.employeeid
                                ORDER BY Surname Asc
                            ");


        while($show1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){

        echo("<tr><td>".$show1['ID Number']."</td><td>".$show1['Surname']."</td><td>".$show1['First Name']."</td><td>".substr($show1['Salary Code Description'],11)."</td></tr>");

        }
        echo ("</table>");

            while($show2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){

            if ($show2['paycode'] == "01 Ordinary" && $show2['ID Number'] == $show1['ID Number']) {
            echo ("<td>".$show1['employeehours']."</td>");
            $normhourspay = ($show1['employeehours'] * $show1['Base Rate']);
            echo ("<td>".$normhourspay."</td></tr>");
            }           else {echo("<td>0</td><td>0</td>");}
                }
```

please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `ID Number`, Surname, `First Name`, `Salary Code Description`,
                                `Base Rate`, `Other Rate`,
                                MAX((case when employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' then (employeehours.employeehours) end)) AS `1.0 Hours`,
                                MAX((case when employeehours.paycode = '02 Overtime 1.5' then (employeehours.employeehours) end)) AS `1.5 Hours`,
                                MAX((case when employeehours.paycode = '03 Overtime 2.0' then (employeehours.employeehours) end)) AS `2.0 Hours`,
                                MAX((case when employeehours.paycode = '78 Crib' then (employeehours.employeehours) end)) AS `Crib`,
                                MAX((case when employeehours.paycode = 'CZ Meal Allowance PS' then (employeehours.employeehours) end)) AS `Meal Allowance`,
                                MAX((case when employeehours.paycode = '86Y Sick with Cert' then (employeehours.employeehours) end)) AS `Sick with Cert`,
                                MAX((case when employeehours.paycode = '86N Sick without Cert' then (employeehours.employeehours) end)) AS `Sick without Cert`,
                                MAX((case when employeehours.paycode = '87 Sick without Pay' then (employeehours.employeehours) end)) AS `Sick without Pay`,
                                MAX((case when employeehours.paycode = '83 Annual Leave' then (employeehours.employeehours) end)) AS `Annual Leave`,
                                MAX((case when employeehours.paycode = '95 RDO Taken' then (employeehours.employeehours) end)) AS `RDO Taken`,
                                MAX((case when employeehours.paycode = '85 LSL' then (employeehours.employeehours) end)) AS `LSL`,
                                MAX((case when employeehours.paycode = '61 Shift 17.5' then (employeehours.employeehours) end)) AS `Shift 17.5`
                                FROM payroll.employeedatanew INNER JOIN payroll.employeehours ON employeedatanew.`ID Number` = employeehours.employeeid
                                Group By Surname
                                ORDER BY Surname asc, `1.0 Hours` desc, `1.5 Hours` desc, `2.0 Hours` desc
```

This did the trick, thanks for everyone viewing :)